# python pandas concat : ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 9), indices imply (4, 5)

Tags: python, pandas

> I am logging into various network devices and trying to concat the
>   output. Below is the script i am running and its working fine
>   perfectly. I am facing the issue when i am trying to Concat the output
>   of po1, allin1, sta1, saa1, stn1. I have given the output of all the
>   variable below. po1 will be the source here, if any of the index is
>   not available in other variables it need to show "NAn".  If you have
>   issue on understanding the question, please let me know.
>
> below is the error I am getting. I am getting this error when i put the axis = 1.

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-dce15d2880ec> in <module>()
----> 1 csv_data1 = pd.concat([po1.set_index('Interface'), allin1.set_index('Interface'), sta1.set_index('Interface'), saa1.set_index('Interface'), stn1.set_index('Interface')],1, sort=True).reset_index()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    224                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    225                        copy=copy, sort=sort)
--> 226     return op.get_result()
    227 
    228 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in get_result(self)
    421             new_data = concatenate_block_managers(
    422                 mgrs_indexers, self.new_axes, concat_axis=self.axis,
--> 423                 copy=self.copy)
    424             if not self.copy:
    425                 new_data._consolidate_inplace()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in concatenate_block_managers(mgrs_indexers, axes, concat_axis, copy)
   5423         blocks.append(b)
   5424 
-> 5425     return BlockManager(blocks, axes)
   5426 
   5427 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in __init__(self, blocks, axes, do_integrity_check)
   3280 
   3281         if do_integrity_check:
-> 3282             self._verify_integrity()
   3283 
   3284         self._consolidate_check()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in _verify_integrity(self)
   3491         for block in self.blocks:
   3492             if block._verify_integrity and block.shape[1:] != mgr_shape[1:]:
-> 3493                 construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
   3494         if len(self.items) != tot_items:
   3495             raise AssertionError('Number of manager items must equal union of '

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   4841         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   4842     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 4843         passed, implied))
   4844 
   4845 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 9), indices imply (4, 5)
```

> ```
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 9), indices imply (4, 5)
> ```

```
switch = ['chi41vg224r3', 'chi41vg224r2', 'chi41s12', 'chi41s5', 'chi41s4', 'chi41s7', 'chi41s6', 'chi41s3', 'chi41m1', 'chi41m1', 'chi41m1', 'chidc41m4', 'chidc41m4', 'chidc41m4', 'chidc41m4']
port = ['Fas 0/0', 'Fas 0/0', 'Gig 1/1/2', 'Ten 6/1', 'Ten 6/1', 'Ten 6/1', 'Ten 6/1', 'Ten 6/1', 'Gig 3/2', 'Gig 5/2', 'Gig 5/1', 'Eth 1/34', 'Eth 1/33', 'Eth 1/32', 'Eth 1/31']
po1 = pd.DataFrame([])
stn1 = pd.DataFrame([])
sta1 = pd.DataFrame([])
saa1 = pd.DataFrame([])
allin1 = pd.DataFrame([])

for (sw, op) in zip(switch, other_port):
    switch1 = {'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'ip': sw, 'username': user, 'password': password, 'port':'22'}
    connect1= ConnectHandler(**switch1)
    opout =connect1.send_command_expect('show run interface '+op)
    connect1.disconnect()
    cfg1 = opout.split('\n')
    parse1 = CiscoConfParse(cfg1)
    intera = parse1.find_objects(r"^interface")
    interf = []
    for interfa in intera:
        tx = interfa.text
        interf.append(tx)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Interface=interf))
    po1 = po1.append(df2)

    ALL1 = parse1.find_children_w_parents(r"^interface", r"^")
    STA1 = parse1.find_children_w_parents(r"^interface", r"switchport trunk allowed ")
    SAA1 = parse1.find_children_w_parents(r"^interface", r"switchport trunk allowed add ")
    STN1 = parse1.find_children_w_parents(r"^interface", r"switchport trunk native ")

    ALL_T1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*(interf, ALL1))), columns=('Interface', 'ALL1'))
    allin1 = allin1.append(ALL_T1)
    STA_T1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*(interf, STA1))), columns=('Interface', 'STA1'))
    sta1 = sta1.append(STA_T1)
    SAA_T1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*(interf, SAA1))), columns=('Interface', 'SAA1'))
    saa1 = saa1.append(SAA_T1)
    STN_T1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*(interf, STN1))), columns=('Interface', 'STN1'))
    stn1 = stn1.append(STN_T1)

csv_data = pd.concat([po1.set_index('Interface'), allin1.set_index('Interface'), sta1.set_index('Interface'), saa1.set_index('Interface'), stn1.set_index('Interface')],1, sort=True).reset_index()
csv_data.rename(columns={'index': 'NeighborINT'}, inplace=True)
```

> Output of po1 :

```
    Interface
0   interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1
0   interface GigabitEthernet3/2
0   interface GigabitEthernet5/2
0   interface GigabitEthernet5/1
```

> Output of allin1 :

```
    Interface                       ALL1
0   interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2  description uplink to chi41m2
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 description Uplink
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 description Uplink
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 description Uplink
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 description Uplink
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 description Uplink
0   interface GigabitEthernet3/2    description CHI41LABFW1-Eth1
0   interface GigabitEthernet5/2    description trunk to chi41m2
0   interface GigabitEthernet5/1    description trunk to chi41m2
```

> output of sta1 :

```
    Interface                       STA1
0   interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2  switchport trunk allowed vlan 20,41,99-101,10...
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20,41,45,102,10...
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20,41,45,102,10...
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20,41,106,107,1...
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20,41,99-101,10...
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20,41,100,101,1...
```

> output of saa1 (here its empty since, none match in the above script):

```
Interface   SAA1
```

> output of stn1 :

```
    Interface                       STN1
0   interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2  switchport trunk native vlan 41
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk native vlan 41
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk native vlan 41
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk native vlan 41
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk native vlan 41
0   interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1 switchport trunk native vlan 41
```

Comment: i can run without error when i mention the axis=0, but the output is not the expected one. not able to mention the result here since its too much data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the output after adding `dropduplicates` and use `merge`
>   instead `concat`.

```
po1_n = po1.drop_duplicates()
allin1_n = allin1.drop_duplicates()
sta1_n = sta1.drop_duplicates()
saa1_n = saa1.drop_duplicates()
stn1_n = stn1.drop_duplicates()
csv_data1 = po1_n.merge(allin1_n, on='Interface', how='outer').merge(sta1_n, on='Interface', how='outer').merge(saa1_n, on='Interface', how='outer').merge(stn1_n, on='Interface', how='outer')
```